# Not able to set ShadowColor in react-native android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, shadowbox

## Environment

- Environment:

  - OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1
  - Node: 8.9.1
  - Yarn: 0.17.10
  - npm: 5.6.0
  - Watchman: 4.7.0
  - Xcode: Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
  - Android Studio: 2.3 AI-162.4069837
- Packages: (installed)

  - react: 16.0.0
  - react-native: 0.51.0

## Steps to Reproduce

#### Run this code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.boxShadow, shadow]}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>LOGIN</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>);
  }
}
const shadow = {
  shadowColor: '#30C1DD',
  shadowRadius: 10,
  shadowOpacity: 0.6,
  elevation: 8,
  shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: 4
  }
}
const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  boxShadow: {
    width: 200,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#ed7171',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  text: {
    color: '#ffffff'
  }
};
export default App;
```

## Expected Behavior

Is there way to achieve like this Shadow in Android

[image: buttonshadow]

as shadow Props of react-native only supports in iOS

- **color need to be changed**
- Tried `elevation` but can not change default **greyed** color
- able to achieve in ios with `shadowColor` props but not in android as it is only support iOS

## Actual Behavior

See sample code and preview.

- It should be work for android too.
- Shadow color is always grey, however I tried to change..

## Reproducible Demo

This is sample snapshot in which I can only get shadow with elevation with only grey color [default].

[image: screen shot 2017-12-15 at 4 56 54 pm]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 4):

As of now the only ways to add shadow are using

```
elevation :value
```

for Android version >5

or to use

```
https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow
```

This is a third party plugin but it supports colour although it doesn't support RGB till now

> Since there is no "shadow" attribute in style list of Android, if we want to add a shadow effect on a component, we must patch a PNG-24 picture, but it's so non-graceful; therefore here comes an SVG shadow plugin to help with this problem. We suggest you to use native shadow on iOS

Comment: I know this answer is not the best solution to the issue but @Bhavan Patel needed urgent help so I shared this information I was able to research up on this topic.I appreciate any suggestions to improve this answer.Thank You

Answer (score 2):

**

> You can use LinearGradient trick

**

https://hashnode.com/post/is-there-any-good-alternative-to-elevations-for-android-in-react-native-cjc600tva00pfuzwup50xv01z

**Updated:**

your now able to add shadow color in react native 0.64

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
{
   backgroundColor:"#fff",
   elevation:4,
   shadowColor:"blue",
}
```

It's not exactly similar to expected behaviour by that's the best we have right now without using any external packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [react-native-shadow-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shadow-2) library to easily add different colored shadows, even gradient shadows

```
<Shadow distance={4} startColor='rgba(42, 255, 42, 0.4)' finalColor='rgba(42, 255, 42, 0.05)' >
  <View style={{width:200,height:80}}>
    <Text>TEST!</Text>
  </View>
</Shadow>
```

Answer (score 0):

We are now able to set `shadowColor` on Android API 28 and above, however, you must also set an `elevation` of greater than 0 and `backgroundColor` must be set to something other than `transparent`.

Here's an example of what is working for me:

```
headerShadow: {
      shadowColor: colorSet.primaryForeground, 
      elevation: 10, // elevation must be set
      backgroundColor : 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.1)' // background color must be set
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

Use elevation to implement shadows on RN Android. [Added elevation prop #27](https://github.com/beefe/react-native-picker/issues/27)

`<View elevation={5}> </View>`

Comment: He asked about `shadowColor`